How to divided a plot along the y axis
I have a data frame like this
df <- data.frame(Category=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"), 
                 Value=c(10,15,17,8,20,23,19,7), 
                 Time=c("Time1", "Time2", "Time1", "Time3", "Time2", "Time1", "Time3", "Time1"))

I'm plotting the graph using this code
ggplot(df, aes(x=Time, y=Value, label=Category)) + 
  geom_text() + 
  theme_minimal()  


I want to divide the graph into plots that have the y-ranges from 0 to 10, 10 to 15, 15 to 20, 20 and over.
I am using this code but it doesn't produce the expected graph.
ggplot(df, aes(x=Time, y=Value, label=Category)) + 
  geom_text() + 
  theme_minimal()  + facet_grid(Time ~ ., scales='free')

I hope to receive some help with this. Many thanks!

Please accept the answer below if it answers your question.

First you need to define the y-range categories
df$Range <- cut(df$Value, breaks = c(0, 10, 15, 20, Inf), labels = c("0-10", "10-15", "15-20", "20+"))

Then you can plot with the facet_grid()
ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = Value, label = Category)) + 
  geom_text() + 
  theme_minimal() +
  facet_grid(. ~ Range, scales = 'free_y')


